# How can I avoid clipping in the object?

Tags: modeling, mesh

today I followed a tutorial and at the end of the tutorial I saw that my mesh flickers.

I don't know how I should describe this problem or how to name it, that is why I just assumed its clipping.

Here is a short youtube video where you can see my problem: [Youtube Link](https://youtu.be/382l6c8jt3g)

Just look at the mesh and you see what I mean.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What that looks like is Z-fighting (2 faces occupying the same space - the renderer doesn't know which one to display in "front", so it flickers back and forth). Try selecting your whole mesh in edit mode then pressing M (merge) and selecting by _Distance_. If there were overlaps, it should show a deleted vert count at the bottom.

Comment: or perhaps you've duplicated the object and the overlapping is happening in Object mode

Comment: Thank you so much this really helped me. Turns out merging these things together was the solution. But can you tell me how I can prevent this from happening in the future?